# MVC 5: How to query a second table based on an ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm not sure if I phrased the question correctly. Using MVC 5, on .NET 4.5.1, and Entity FrameWork 6.1.3. I started off with an Oracle database. In Visual Studio I built my models, views, controls at the start of my project based on a table called Missions. Missions has several fields that are user ID fields (Added By, Modified By, Etc.) These IDs are listed in a table called Crew along with the user's name and other info. I want to display the user's name instead of the ID in all the views for Mission. Do I manually create a new Model pointing to the Crew table or is there a way to have VS create it for me like I was able to do at the start of my project? Do I even need to do that if I don't need any CRUD operations on the Crew table? How can I join the Crew IDs with the Modified By ID? Thanks.

Currently my View looks like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MODIFIED_BY)
```

I would want something like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MODIFIED_BY.Full_Name)
```

UPDATE: Here is what I ended up doing. Not sure if this is totally the backwards way of doing things, but it worked for me. I started off by adding my new lookup fields to my model like this:

```
[StringLength(2000)]
[DisplayName("Modified By")]
[NotMapped]
public string MODIFIED_BY_FULL_NAME { get; set; }
```

Also in the model, I updated the code for the MODIFY_BY property like this

```
private decimal? modified_by;
[DisplayName("Modified By")]
public decimal? MODIFIED_BY
{
    get
    {
        return modified_by;
    }
    set
    {
        modified_by = value;
        if (value != null)
        {
          Mission db = new Mission();
          var name = db.CREW.First(n => n.CREW_ID == value);
          if (name != null)
          {
              MODIFIED_BY_FULL_NAME = name.CREW_FULL_NAME;
          }
        }
     }
  }
```

so whenever the MODIFIED_BY property gets set, I do a lookup and populate the MODIFIED_BY_FULL_NAME property as well. Then in my View I just use the new property to display the full name with this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MODIFIED_BY_FULL_NAME)
```

The big downside here is all the looking up I have to do which takes a long time. Also since these new properties are not mapped, I can't use OrderBy or even search on them. I have to convert the value back to the ID value first. This is why I am thinking I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you saying the Crew table exists in the database, but not in your EntityFramework model?

Comment: If you're using EF, do you have your navigation properties set up? If so, then you should just be able to do `modelItem.MODIFIED_BY.Full_Name` or some variant of.

Comment: The Crew table exists in my database but not in my EF model. I could create the model, but I wasn't sure how to "link" it to the ID fields of Mission. I was also wondering if there was some way to have Visual Studio create the model and link it for me kind of how I started the project off. I'm not sure what navigation properties are, so maybe that is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: If you can give relationship between table then you can access the desired tables data using ID or something like "Lazy Loading".